# Refresh JWT authentication token on ios

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, jwt

I'm working on application, with JWT Authentication. Server side doesn't provide a mechanism for auto-updated token after the `expiry date`, but I've been provided a special method for refresh token.

Actually I have no idea how to check `expiry date` properly. I thought of setting `Timer` for `expiry date`, but the timer doesn't work when the app is in the background. Also I thought of checking token validity in `viewWillAppear`, but by doing so, the amount of server requests increase dramatically, which is not good enough either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you found the correct way to do this yet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create a method in your `AppDelegate` that handles your token acquisition. Then do something like this

```
func getToken() {
    //Whatever you need to do here.
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "tokenAcquisitionTime")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tokenAcquired"), object: nil)
}
```

Create a timer variable in your `AppDelegate`

```
var timer: Timer!
```

Create the following methods in your `AppDelegate`

```
func postTokenAcquisitionScript() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func tick() {
    if let time = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "tokenAcquisitionTime") as? Date {
        if Date().timeIntervalSince(time) > 3600 { //You can change '3600' to your desired value. Keep in mind that this value is in seconds. So in this case, it is checking for an hour
            timer.invalidate()
            getToken()
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching`, `willEnterForeground`, and `didEnterBackground`, do the following

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Your code here
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(postTokenAcquisitionScript), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tokenAcquired"), object: nil)
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Your code here
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(postTokenAcquisitionScript), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tokenAcquired"), object: nil)
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Your code here
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tokenAcquired"), object: nil)
}
```